# what libraries are required to develop an ocr based android app for mathematical expression evaluation in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to android and i want to develop an android app that can capture image of mathematical expression and display the evaluation on screen,but i have no idea about any library,can anyone tell me what libraries are there to do so ?